# Finding eigenvectors of a differential operator

Tags: finite-element-method, eigenvalues

How can I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors(numerically) of the below matrix equation:

$
  \qquad \hat{A}\left({\begin{array}{c}
   y_1(x,\theta)\\
   y_2(x,\theta)  \\
  \end{array} } \right)=
  a\left({\begin{array}{c}
   y_1(x,\theta)\\
   y_2(x,\theta)  \\
  \end{array} } \right)
$

Where $\hat{A}$ is a differential operator that can be represented as 2X2 matrix, with second derivatives with respect to $x$ and $\theta$.

I wish to find the functions $y_1$ and $y_2$, and the eigenvalues $a$ numerically with Mathematica. I tried using NDEigensystem but to no success.

If needed I can also specify the operator $\hat{A}$ in matrix form.

#### Edit

Here is my attempted code:

```
f1[x_, θ_] := x^2 + Cos[θ]
f2[x_, θ_] := x^2 + x + Cos[θ]
eqns = 
  {-D[D[y1[x, θ], x], x] - D[D[y1[x, θ], θ], θ] + f1[x, θ]*y1[x, θ] + x*y2[x, θ], 
   -D[D[y2[x, θ], x], x] - D[D[y2[x, θ], θ], θ] + f2[x, θ]*y2[x, θ] + x*y1[x, θ]}

NDEigensystem[eqns, {y1, y2}, {{x, -5, 5}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}}, 4]
```

Comment: Publish your code for clarity.

Comment: I added my code

Comment: For a differential equation. I thought that I would need BC if I used methods like NDSolve, but when using NDEigensystem for some differential operators I usually did not specify them, so I didn't think that I to specify them. However, the boundary conditions are going to be periodicity in $\theta$ in $2Pi$, that the functions y1 and y2 are going to be even or odd functions, and that at x=0 we can take y1 to be y2 =1.

Comment: For example, if I want to find energy eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a quartic potential, simply writing: NDEigensystem[-y''[x]/2 + y[x]*x^4, y, {x, -5, 5}, 4] will find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors without specifying the BC

Comment: Yes, but it will assume that you want $y(-5)=0$ and $y(5)=0$, not periodicity.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for clarifying. How should I implement the BC conditions in this case? Assuming that I bound x by +-5 similarly to above.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple typo. Use:

```
NDEigensystem[eqns, {y1, y2}, {x, -5, 5}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 4]
(* {{-0.0329282, 0.526089, 0.940386, 1.4994},... *)
```

not the `{{x, -5, 5}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}}` you have.

Answer (score 2):

Homogeneous boundary conditions are used here.

```
f1[x_, θ_] := x^2 + Cos[θ]
f2[x_, θ_] := x^2 + x + Cos[θ]
eqns = {-D[D[y1[x, θ], x], x] - 
    D[D[y1[x, θ], θ], θ] + 
    f1[x, θ]*y1[x, θ] + 
    x*y2[x, θ], -D[D[y2[x, θ], x], x] - 
    D[D[y2[x, θ], θ], θ] + 
    f2[x, θ]*y2[x, θ] + x*y1[x, θ]};

{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{eqns, 
    DirichletCondition[{y1[x, θ] == 0, y2[x, θ] == 0}, 
     x == -5 || x == 5], 
    DirichletCondition[{y1[x, θ] == 0, 
      y2[x, θ] == 0}, θ == 0 || θ == 2 Pi]}, {y1,
     y2}, {x, -5, 5}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 4];

{Table[Plot3D[
   funs[[i, 1]][x, θ], {x, -5, 5}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> vals[[i]]], {i, 4}], 
 Table[Plot3D[
   funs[[i, 2]][x, θ], {x, -5, 5}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> vals[[i]]], {i, 4}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]